# How to override config property for one Unittest in Quarkus

Tags: unit-testing, quarkus

In my Quarkus-Application an Observer of `StartupEvent` inserts default data into my database if a specific config-property is true. For one particular UnitTest I want my database to be empty.

I would think that there is some way to override configuration values for one unittest. Is that true, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using test profiles

https://quarkus.io/blog/quarkus-test-profiles/

Comment: Thanks a lot. This indeed seems to be the way to go about this nowadays... I will mark this as accepted even though I cannot verify if this one actually solves the problem as that particular project is long done. If someone else has anything to add that would be very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried out by using a test profile for that property in your application.properties ?

Something like this:

—default value is A

myProp=A

—this is the test profile, which overrides the default value

%tst.myProp=B

Comment: This is the way I am handling it right now. But the problem is that this property would then be set for all of my tests and not just for a single one.